# Error message in intellisense popup is displayed twice

Tags: visual-studio

On a new Visual Studio install I'm getting this problem:

[image]

Error messages are doubled, just without a hyperlink. This goes for all error/warning messages in Visual Studio, and I could find any info on this particular problem. Is there anything specific I should look at, so I don't have to reset everything?

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 - Version 16.10.0, everything is up to date.

Comment: Happens for me as well, since a long time. I always blamed it on Resharper, but I guess you did not install that, did you?

Comment: @PMFNo, I don't have Resharper, and reseting my environment settings didn't help either.

Comment: I see this problem not always, but very often. On at least three completely different systems. I have learned to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too and only since upgrading to v16.10.0. You can make it temporarily go away by deleting the .vs folder inside of the solution folder, but it seems to always come back.